# Oil selection for Kia's and Hyundai's

Tags: oil, hyundai, kia

I have a simple question, but it has sent me down a rabbit hole. I want to start changing my own oil in our 2017 Kia Sedona. They recommend a conventional oil 5W30 that meets the ACEA A5/B5 rating. And I can't find any conventional oils that meet this. If I look at synthetics I see Pennzoil Platinum and Mobil 1 has the ACEA A5/B5 rating. I also found that recently (5 years or so) Castrol and others lost the ACEA A5/B5 rating. Seems like something changed to get this certification.

You might say, so, use the synthetic oil then. But I want to do things "by the books" to ensure I don't void our warranty on the vehicle. For example I'll be using OEM oil filters, etc. So if like to stick with a conventional oil if possible.

For reference I live in Ontario, Canada. I've been looking at auto parts stores and the major stores like Costco and Canadian Tire.

Thanks!

Comment: Won't you void the warrranty by changing the oil yourself? And which oil was the maintenance shop using (should be on the invoices)?

Comment: @WeatherVane - In the States (and I'd assume there are laws in many other countries, too) there are laws which protects the consumer for changing the oil changed or doing any other maintenance to your own vehicle without voiding the warranty. You just have to have proof you did the maintenance. That's through receipts and even video/photo logging what you've done. The car manufacturer cannot force you to utilize any particular service to maintain your warranty. They can dictate what you put into your car, like the type, grade, or specification of your oil.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I would have thought (with no disrepect intended to OP) that the warranty would support a *provably* competent person doing the maintenance. For example, my non-franchised local garage did within-warranty servicing for me, but they send their mechanics on courses to stay up-to-speed in their competence.

Comment: Changing oil isn't rocket science. Yet I see "competent garage mechanics" bumbling it all the time. Realistically that has no bearing on whether the warranty stays intact over changing the oil yourself. [Here is what the Federal Trade Commision](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0138-auto-warranties-routine-maintenance) has to say about it. What I'm talking about is covered under the [Magnuson Moss Warranty Act of 1975](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnuson%E2%80%93Moss_Warranty_Act).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 fair enough. I was thinking of what the FTC says: *"there may be certain situations where a repair may not be covered. For example, if you or your mechanic replaced a belt improperly and your engine is damaged as a result, your manufacturer or dealer may deny responsibility for fixing the engine under the warranty."* But it also says *"must be able to demonstrate that it was the improper belt replacement — rather than some other defect — that caused the damage to your engine. The warranty would still be in effect for other parts of your car."*

Comment: @WeatherVane - You don't have to prove you are competent to do the work, you just have to prove the work was done right. This is an interesting topic, however, comments are not the place for it. If you'd like to continue along these lines, I'd suggest you bring up the topic at [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), the site's chat room.